# Find the line closest to 2 2D points passing through a 3rd point

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Given 3 homogeneous 2D points, $p=[p_x,p_y,1]$, $q=[q_x,q_y,1]$, and $v=[v_x,v_y,v_z]$, with $p$ and $q$ finite (last coordinate is $1$), but $v_z$ maybe either $1$ - finite or $0$ - at infinity:

Find two new 2D points $p'$, $q'$ s.t. $d(p,p')+d(q,q')$ is minimized, with $d(p,q)$ the Euclidian distance) and $<l\equiv p' \times q', v> = 0$.

In words, find the line $l=[l_1,l_2,l_3]$ passing through $v$, that minimizes the sum of the Euclidean distances of $p$ and $q$ from $l$.

How can I find $l$? 
Even if only for the finite case where $v_z=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for the infinite case ($v_z=0$), the solution will in general not be unique: any line passing *between* $p$ and $q$ will give the same distance. This is because as you move the line by an Euclidean distance of $a$ orthogonal to its direction, one distance will decrease by $a$ while the other will increase by that same amount, keeping the sum constant. This is why such approximation tasks usually minimize not the sum of errors but the sum of *squared* errors, often (but not necessarily) measured not orthogonal to the line but in a given direction.

Now for the finite case. Imagine a line which passes between $p$ and $q$. Rotating that line around $v$, you will increase one distance while decreasing the other. The change will be greater the farther a point is from the center of location. So you want to distance of the far point to decrease, even if the distance of the near point will increase by a smaller amount in the process. You can keep this argument up until the line actually passes through the far point. So the general solution would be this: compute the Euclidean distances $d(p,v)$ and $d(q,v)$. Obtain $l$ by connecting $v$ to the point wiuth the larger distance, completely ignoring the closer point.

In the corner case of $d(p,v)=d(q,v)$, you can choose the point to connect to arbitrarily. Both $v\times p$ and $v\times q$ will yield the same distance, while any line between them will result in a larger sum of distances. As a line connecting $v$ to either $p$ or $q$ will provide an optimal result for the infinite case as well, you can *always* choose $l$ to be the connection of $v$ to either of $p$ or $q$, taking care in the choice if the distances are finite and different.

Comment: Good answer! I was expecting an algebraic answer, and you gave an intuitive geometric one. You were right in your comment, I'd actually like to minimize the sum of *squared* distances. How does this change affect the solution?

Comment: @AdiShavit, it changes the answer completely. Look for existing material on that topic, and ask a new question if you can't find a solution to that yourself.

Comment: I reverted to the original question and accepted your excellent answer. The new question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263601/find-the-line-closest-ssd-to-2-2d-points-passing-through-a-3rd-point)